# Wi-Fi RT3290 device not ready on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless

The Wi-Fi menu shows "**device not ready**" instead of available networks, I tried various solutions but none worked for me, I did a run with the wireless info script here: [wirless-info](https://paste.ubuntu.com/24940052/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `ifconfig wlan0 up` as root:

```
sudo su
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

**Note:** `wlan0` is the logical name for my wireless card, to find yours run: `sudo lshw -C network`

Answer (score 0):

In your logs, please see:

```
ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_wait_csr_ready: Error - Unstable hardware
```

See also here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2309044 Especially, my post #4 and following.

Before you proceed, I'd download and try a live session for both a newer and later Ubuntu version to see if it helps. Also, I suggest that you turn off 802.11N and AC, if you have it, in the router to see if it helps.

If your device is intermittent, then I suggest that you first reseat the device in its PCI slot. Second, reset the computer's BIOS to defaults. Finally, we might get some additional information by checking the logs related to the PCI bus. In your wireless info we see:

```
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp.<snip>
```

When the device is *not* working, check the log:

```
dmesg | grep 09:00
```

I wonder if the device is defective.

Comment: The thing is it very rarely works, I booted from a live session and it worked, but i can't be sure because sometimes it does work on the installed OS. Is there a way to know if it'll always work? By the way here is wireless-info for when it works https://paste.ubuntu.com/24948077/

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: Here is the output of `dmesg | grep 09:00` when it's not working 
`[    0.688362] pci 0000:09:00.0: [1814:3290] type 00 class 0x028000
[    0.688399] pci 0000:09:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xb2510000-0xb251ffff]
[    0.688512] pci 0000:09:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot
[    0.688547] pci 0000:09:00.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.688600] pci 0000:09:00.1: [1814:3298] type 00 class 0x0d1100
[    0.688636] pci 0000:09:00.1: reg 0x10: [mem 0xb2500000-0xb250ffff]
[    0.688746] pci 0000:09:00.1: supports D1
[    0.688748] pci 0000:09:00.1: PME# supported from D0 D1 D3hot`